# iOS app is closed from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsuserdefaults

I made an iOS app, in that am using `NSUserDefaults`.If app is closed from the background I want to remove the strings which are stored in `NSUserDefaults`.Can anyone give me the solutions for find the app is closed from background.

Comment: What do you mean by "closed"? Do mean you want to clear the `NSUserDefaults` if the user force-quits your app?

Comment: u can clear your `NSUserDefaults` in  2 ways, one **applicationWillTerminate** another one **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** is called at initial time only

Comment: thanq karthik .. its solved

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Data stored in NSUserDefaults is supposed to be persistent. If you don't want it to persist, why are you storing it there?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Post this as answer so that OP can accept it...

Comment: @FahimParkar -- tanx for your information but questioner replied thanq karthik .. its solved , if i posted the answer he accepted

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : I meant post as an answer so that OP can mark it as accepted and others will also see the accepted answer as solution...

Comment: If you really need to clean NSUserDefaults then i guess your only chance is to set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to YES in your .plist. But this way you loose all background modes - your app will completely close when user taps home button also.

Answer (score 1):

You do not get any notification when your app is removed from background running. The app is killed by the OS with no warning of any kind.

When your app enters the background, you have no way to know if will be started fresh or simply return to the foreground.

Also why do you need this? if you save something in NSUSerDefaults then it is supposed to be persistent. If possible let us know your scenario where you require this feature so that we can provide you some other approach.

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is for your first sentence...

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is not called when your app is force-killed from the background or killed due to memory pressure.

Comment: Yes, I tested applicationWillTerminate is not called

Comment: @thavasidurai : how you are testing? did you put `NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate");` inside `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {` in AppDelegate? I tested and its working...

Comment: I kept the breakpoint but it is not called i will try again by putting NSLog and let you know

Comment: No applicationWillTerminate is not called

Comment: i think you tried the method didenterbackground

Comment: Nope I am sure i tried it in - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application but it is not worked, I am not sure why it is not worked for me

Answer (score 1):

u can clear your `NSUserDefaults` in  2 ways, one **applicationWillTerminate** another one **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** is called at initial time only

```
// if u terminated your application surly it remove the all keys and other local DB 

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{


 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"addyourkeys"]; 
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

 }
```

**choice No :2**

```
   // it is called only initially time , u can also follow your work at here.. but no need at here the applicationWillTerminate will follow the work 

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{


 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"addyourkeys"]; 
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

 }
```